# Give Threads their own spawned Expect: Unsupported ref type: GLOB

Tags: multithreading, perl, fork, expect

I have a bunch of devices I have to logon to and run a few commands on them. As it takes time and there are a bunch of them I want to parallelise the task, do a few of them at the same time. I've done it with `Net::Telnet` however I have to use `Expect.pm` now.

In my main thread I fill up the `@FW` array with hashrefs called `\%host` thusly:

```
my $EXPECT =  new Expect();
$EXPECT->spawn("ssh $username\@$ip");
$host{'expect'} = $EXPECT;

push(@FW, \%host);
```

Then I do a thread pool/queue i nicked from perlmonks which I've used for a few other things so I know that approach does work however I'm getting the error (check my comment in the code below)

```
sub getWorkItems {
    my $host = pop(@FW);
    return $host ? $host : undef;
}

our $THREADS = 3;
my $Qwork    = new Thread::Queue;
my $Qresults = new Thread::Queue;

my @pool = map {
    threads->create(\&worker, $Qwork, $Qresults)
} 1 .. $THREADS;

while (my $workItem = getWorkItems()) { # ERROR HERE: Unsupported ref type: GLOB
    $Qwork->enqueue($workItem);
}
$Qwork->enqueue((undef) x $THREADS);

sub worker {
    my $tid = threads->tid;
    my ($Qwork, $Qresults) = @_;
    while (my $host = $Qwork->dequeue()) {
        backup($host->{'expect'}, $host->{'hostname'}, $host->{'ip'}, $host->{'username'}, $host->{'password'});
    }
    $Qresults->enqueue(undef); ## Signal this thread is finished
}

for (1 .. $THREADS) {
    while (my $result = $Qresults->dequeue()) {
        print "T$_  $result", "\n";
    }
}

foreach (@pool) {
    $_->join();
}
```

I've read on CPAN that I have to give each thread its own spawned expect, but what am I doing wrong? I'm trying to pass the object via the same hash along with the other arguments heres how the `backup` sub begins:

```
sub backup {
    my ($EXPECT, $hostname, $ip, $username, $password) = @_;

    print "$EXPECT, $hostname, $ip, $username, $password\n";

    my $auth = $EXPECT->expect(3, -re => "authenticity of host");
```

(I don't see that print statement)

Again, this question is not about my use of Expect (that works), it's about how to use Expect in threads.

Comment: just a side note, picking `Expect` over `Net::SSH2` seems like picking shoes over bike brakes.

Comment: Well if the proprietary implementation part of the firmware or w/e it is of the devices I'm automating above takes `Net::SSH2` I'd be amazed, I've never made that work and for linux to linux interaction I .. well use backticks and system() as it's usually basic stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread::Queue` uses `threads::shared` under the hood, and `threads::shared` does not support all Perl data types. Especially it looks like GLOBs are not supported.

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $foo :shared;
for my $val (1, "foo", qr{regexp}, ["array"], {"ha"=>"sh"}, \*STDOUT, sub { }) {
    eval { $foo = shared_clone($val) };
    warn "Setting to $val failed: $@" if $@;
}
```

With a threaded perl 5.18.1 I get:

```
Setting to (?^:regexp) failed: Unsupported ref type: REGEXP at shared.pl line 8.
Setting to GLOB(0x80184e798) failed: Unsupported ref type: GLOB at shared.pl line 8.
Setting to CODE(0x801aa78e8) failed: Unsupported ref type: CODE at shared.pl line 8.
```

I don't think you can do anything about it, other than not using threads, but instead using event-based mechanisms (`Event.pm`, `AnyEvent`, `POE` ...) or even think about using traditional `pipe`+`fork`.

Comment: Yes I might try with either forking or dirtier still, call a separate script altogether with parameters per each device, essentially a fork but using the OS like a n00b ahah.